# django can not close message.info when click crossing button

Tags: django

Not sure what happened. I am using Django messages with bootstrap and once it pops up, it cant seem to close when I click the "x" button.

Here are the code for views.py:

```
def post_list(request, slug):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        msg='Thanks for checking out '
        messages.info(request, msg)
    return render(request, 'Reddit_app/post_list.html',  {'posts': posts, 'subreddits':subreddits, 'station': station, "user_score": user_score})
```

here is the settings in the file settings.py

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.messages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+"/templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
        messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
        messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
        messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
        messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
        messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
 }
```

here is the template part

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" >
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: how about your js, you didn't post its code, i believe it is the one that does the closing

Comment: in your views you are not closing the `msg=' Thanks for checking out ` it should be  `msg= 'Thanks for checking out ' `

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih just added the js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" >
      
        <button type="button" 
        onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();">close</button>
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Use the above code in templates to close the alert